# select, update, delete ASPNETDB.mdf profile table

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

salam 
i have custome create user wizard control having additional properties which is saving in the profile table of the ASPNETDB.mdf database so how can i select , update and delete those properties which i define in the create user wizard and save in the profile table od ASPNETDB.mdf database plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScottGu has an excellent tutorial:

- [How to add a Login, Roles and Profile system to an ASP.NET 2.0 app in only 24 lines of code](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx)

This should help you get started. When you have more specific questions as you develop your code, feel free to ask.

Comment: What? That's not what your question asked.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you forgot the link to this?

[image: Web Site Administration tool]

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx):

> To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the Website menu, click
>   ASP.Net Configuration.